# \resheading command

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

\resheading command is generating text boxes with different alignments (different horizontal margins) for different pages. How can I generate two text boxes on the same margin on two consecutive pages from this command ?The following is the code.

This command is used in the following link for creating resume

https://www.overleaf.com/articles/mandeep-singhs-resume/vzwgxhzhbjxk

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a compilable and minimal working example?

Comment: what more info should io provide?

Comment: You should provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  In particular, `\resheading` is not part of the LaTeX core, so we need to know its definition or which package you are loading from, and how you use it.

Comment: I have attached the overleaf link with the resume format.

Comment: Monika - Please avoid sharing personal details on the web. If possible, please change the source and resume too.

Comment: it is actually the sample resume on their portal. It is not mine.